# WebStorm remote interpreter not working with TSLint

Tags: node.js, docker, webstorm, tslint

I followed this [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/configuring-node-js-interpreters.html#d30152e521) to setup a remote interpreter with Docker in WebStorm, now I would like to use it as the interpreter for the TSLint plugin, I get this in the upper window:

[image: tslint missing interpreter]

But when I try to configure the interpreter I only get the option for a local interpreter.

Is there any way to configure it to use the remote one?

This is what I see:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible ATM. Here is official explanation: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25411#comment=27-1906237

> This is the correct behavior described in Help (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/node-js.html)
>
> The reason is that the project Node.js interpreter is used in many places - to run TypeScript service/compiler, external linters, etc. And all these services require local Node.js interpreter, they can't be run remotely. The only place where remote interpreters are supported is Node.js running/debugging. That's why setting up remote interpreter is only possible from Node.js Run configuration

---

There are requests to add support for remote execution for Karma/Mocha/ESLint -- see those tickets -- maybe you will find and answer there (or create new Feature Request ticket if these tickets below do not have clear answer/not suitable for your needs):

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-20824
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-14665
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22179

---

On related note (this comment and around):

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22572#comment=27-1836383

> If so...our Docker integration isn't currently for that use case. Everything to do with the development – linters, build tools, test runners, ts language service, angular language service, angular cli, react project generator, react native, etc. – runs against a local NodeJS and node_modules.